# Auto Create Table On Next Line in ITextSharp

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

[image]

For Example in this Image , I have four Dates of record , may be in next PDF will have 10 dates of record then how to set maximum five number of Dates Record show in a **First-Table** and next five dates show in **Second-Table** just after First-Table (Second Table Auto Generate) in iTextSharp

```
 for (int c = 4; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
                    {
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Columns[c].ToString(), fntMainHeading));
                        cell.Padding = 2;
                        cell.BorderColor = new Color(217, 217, 217);
                        table.AddCell(cell);

                    }
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (ServiceCode == 0 || ServiceCode != Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ServiceCode"]))
                    {
                        ServiceCode = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ServiceCode"]);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["ServiceName"]), fntHeading));
                        cell.Padding = 2;
                        cell.Colspan = col;
                        cell.BorderColor = new Color(217, 217, 217);
                        table.AddCell(cell);
                    }
                    for (int j = 4; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][j]), fntNormalText));
                        cell.Padding = 2;
                        cell.BorderColor = new Color(217, 217, 217);
                        table.AddCell(cell);
                    }
                }
                table.SpacingBefore = 10;
                table.SpacingAfter = 10;
                doc.Add(table);
            }
```